# Having issue with reading excel files in loop due to promise.then() not being called before js moves on to the next i

Tags: javascript, jquery, excel, html

This is what I am trying to do, I have a page on my site that I have set up a file input, and a few buttons that open the file selector, and to run a specific set of code, shown here in a moment. This code works when you only need to read one file at a time, the issue shows itself as soon as you start to  need to read through two files, and due to a requirement from the customer, I have to allow it to accept a range of files all at once and then they can be processed and dealt with.

The problem come from the use of the excel reader library that i am using and I have not been able to find information on my google and SO searches, and even when I have searched through other "similar" routs and possible solutions it seems to only be making the issue worse...

I must figure out how to get multiple files to work with this.

Everything works up to the point where it gets to the xls/xlsx files, the reader function returns a promise that is not resolved before the script moves on to the next file in the list. I have attempted some of my tried and true methods like closure functions and looper functions, but get exceptions on the closures and loopers get completely ignored.

As I am still learning about promises and async functionality, I have no idea how to I don't know force it to wait until the file has been processed... or some how allow it to to recall the `fileName` variable and `i` value to be worked on.

```
<div class="row ml-0 w-100" id="input-file">
    <div class="col-12">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="" class="control-label w-100">Select Files to Upload</label>
            <input type="file" name="files" id="files" class="hidden" multiple>
            <button class="btn btn-info" id="display-fs">Select Files</button>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" id="do-file-work">Process Files</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row ml-0 w-100" id="results"></div>

<script>
    // https://github.com/catamphetamine/read-excel-file
    // built on node, but implemented in a standalone way
    // the below is my current trouble code... It fails due to the values rows, and
    // errors not being defined yet, but when i attempted the looper functions it
    // just ignored the whole then completely... 

    var fileList = [], fileInput = $('input#files')[0], localAssetsList = [];
    $('#display-fs').on('click', function () {
        if ($('input#files')) {
            $('input#files').click();
        }
    });
    $(fileInput).on('change', function (event) {
        fileList = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < fileInput.files.length; i++) {
            fileList.push(fileInput.files[i]);
        }
    });
    $('#do-file-work').on('click', function(e){
        var data = null;
        if (fileList.length == 0) return;
        for (var i = 0; i < fileList.length; i++) {
            var file = fileList[i], extention = file.name.substring(file.name.indexOf('.') + 1, file.name.length), fileName = file.name.substring(0, file.name.indexOf('.'));
            if (extention == 'xls' || extention == 'xlsx') {
                debugger;
                if (fileName.toLowerCase().indexOf('asset') != -1) {
                    readXlsxFile(file).then((function(rows, errors, fileName) {
                        debugger;
                        var data1 = rows;
                        if (data1.length > 0) {
                            $('<div></div>', {
                                id: 'assets-' + i,
                                class: 'col-12 table-responsive',
                                html: $('<table></table>', {
                                    id: fileName,
                                    class: 'table table-sm table-striped'
                                })
                            }).appendTo('#results');
                            $('<thead></thead>', {
                                html: $('<tr></tr>', {
                                    id: fileName + '-header',
                                    class: 'text-nowrap'
                                })
                            }).appendTo('#' + fileName);
                            for (var k = 0; k < data1[0].length; k++) {
                                var element = data1[0][k];
                                $('<th></th>', {
                                    html: element.toString().toUpperCaseFirstWord()
                                }).appendTo('#' + fileName + '-header');
                            }
                            $('<tbody></tbody>', {
                                id: fileName + '-body'
                            }).appendTo('#' + fileName);
                            for (var x = 1; x < data1.length; x++) {
                                var ele = data1[x];
                                if (ele[0] === null){
                                    console.error('Row ' + (x + 1) + ' is missing critical detail in cell 1. Skipping row.');
                                    continue;
                                } else {
                                    for (var n = 0; n < ele.length; n++) {
                                        var y = ele[n];
                                        if (n == 0) {
                                            $('<tr></tr>', {
                                                id: 'row-' + y,
                                                html: $('<td></td>', {
                                                    html: (isNull(y)) ? "": y.toString()
                                                }),
                                                on: {
                                                    click: function (e) {
                                                        if ($(this).hasClass('selected-row')) {
                                                            $(this).removeClass('selected-row');
                                                        } else {
                                                            $(this).addClass('selected-row');
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }).appendTo('#' + fileName + '-body')
                                        } else {
                                            $('<td></td>', {
                                                html: (isNull(y)) ? "": y.toString()
                                            }).appendTo('#row-' + ele[0]);
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    })(rows, errors, fileName)); //this closure doesnt work...
                }
            }
        }
    })
</script>
```

It should go into then(...), bit it is not, and then by the time it would (assuming that the promise is a asynchronous process) the values would have changed and be no longer valid. this is correct for single file loads, but causes the whole function then() to be ignored, causing the files that are excel to be skipped over completely.

I don't know what I am doing wrong, I cannot find enough documentation or help anywhere to resolve the issue on my own, and I am continuing to look.

Any one have suggestions on what I can do to get this thing working like it should?

Comment: You need further study on how Promise objects work: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then

Comment: Ahh Promises not allowed in ie 11 ... darned... oh well i found one that works actually better and its all good thanks. I read the MDN and promises sound fun but our environment sill has a heavy dependence on IE11 ... so all my fun goes to having to shim and prototype things I need...